# checkbox check event is not firing in IE8

Tags: jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer, checkbox, jquery-events

I have a login form on which I have created a checkbox control. To handle it's checked event, I have written code as,

```
 if ($("[id*=chkRememberMe]").is(':checked')) {
                remember = true;
            }
```

In all the browsers except IE 8, if checkbox is checked by user, it returns true. IE8 is returning false.

Not able to understand what is the issue.
Please help me out in this.

Comment: Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TUL7S/).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if ($("[id*=chkRememberMe]").prop('checked') == true) {
    remember = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works fine for me.

```
$('#myform :checkbox').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        // $this will contain a reference to the checkbox   
        if ($this.is(':checked')) {
            // the checkbox was checked 
        } else {
            // the checkbox was unchecked
        }
    });
```

Comment: I am checking if it is checked or not on login button click.

Comment: Have a Variable and change it on and off during click and check for the variable value in login button click and continue your function.

Answer (score 0):

use getElementById document function like following

```
if(document.getElementById("chkRememberMe").checked)
{
    remember = true;
}
```

This will work in any browser

**OR EDIT**

```
remember = document.getElementById("chkRememberMe").checked;
```